# jQuery Ajax is calling two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, frontend

I have an `<input>` tag like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave2" value="Save" onclick="Event(1)" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12" />
```

and this is my script:

```js
function event(loop){
  debugger
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "UpEven.aspx",
    data: { slno: EventNo[0]}
  }).done(function(msg){
    debugger
  })
}
```

After I click on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button, Ajax is called twice. The initial debugger is hit only one time but Ajax is rendering two times.

I want Ajax to call only once on every button click.

Comment: you've shown a function called `event` but onclick calls `Event` ...

Comment: *"initial debugger is hit for only time but ajax is rendering two times"* - What specifically do you mean by that?  If the `debugger` statement at the start of this function is only invoked once then this function is only invoked once.  Please clarify.

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is verify on each call the target object event. Your code does not show it but if I have to guess you might have another html element which also triggers the click event. You can also use preventDefault and (iirc) return false from the function to prevent another invocation. Also if you focus on getting a minimal working example of the problem you might end up discovering what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#btnSave2').click(function () {
      Event(1);
   });
});

function Event(loop) {
   debugger
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "UpEven.aspx",
      data: { slno: EventNo[0] }
   }).done(function (msg) {
      debugger
   });
}
```

```html
/* 

Remove Inline Onclick Attribute:

If you're using jQuery, you can remove the inline onclick attribute from the HTML and bind the event using jQuery. This can help in avoiding any conflicts 

please remove Event(1) function if you write outside a function called.

*/

<input type="button" id="btnSave2" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12" />
```